# JAVA - Use SSL External Certificate to secure A Socket Server

Tags: java, ssl, serversocket

I have a web application which is secured on port 443 by a SSL certificate (from GoDaddy).

Now i need to secure also a TCP port where a Socket Server should be listening.

I would like to use the certificate i already have (should I?)

So i imported the crt file and the private key into a keystore using openssl in this way

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey mykey.key -out keystore.jks
```

if i do `keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks`  i see my certificate inside.

Now, in my SocketServer class i do the following

```
 final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(new File("/home/ubuntu/certificates/keystore.jks"), password);

final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("NewSunX509");


keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);

final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");//"SSL" "TLS"

context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

SSLServerSocketFactory sslssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

            serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslssf.createServerSocket(port);
```

Now i would like to check

if i try to standard 443 port on my web app

```
openssl s_client -connect host:443 -showcerts -servername www.host.com
```

i get all the info about the certificate.
If i go to my socket port

```
openssl s_client -connect host:9000 -showcerts -servername www.host.com
```

i get

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
4542131820:error:14004410:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.100.4/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:1200:SSL alert number 40
4542131820:error:140040E5:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:ssl handshake failure:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.100.4/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:585:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1589219540
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

But also if i try to connect from the host itself

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:9000 -showcerts -servername www.host.com
```

i get

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
139667580962456:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 334 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1589219636
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

It looks like no certificate is been taken into account...

EDIT

When i try to connect with openssl, on the app logs i see this exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

Comment: That file is actually a PKCS12 (or P12) not a JKS, but the name only confuses people; if `keytool` works on it without `-storetype` you must be using java 8 or higher, and yes this should work AFAICT. Does your app have a log, and if so what does it say? If not can you catch the exception and get a traceback? If nothing else, set system property `javax.net.debug=ssl` and see what that says.

Comment: I'm on java11. I added what i read on my logs on the app when i try to connect no cipher suites in common

Comment: I didn't notice the first time, but your code isn't actually using this keystore. Instead of `SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()` use `context.getServerSocketFactory()`.

Comment: Thansk mate!!! This is the real answer, you saved my week. If you write an answer, i will accept it